# linux system stuck and show kernel log

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

The system version is centos6.5, it stuck today, and there is no log at all in `/var/log/messages`, When I connect the host with a display device, it shows log blow:
[image: log]

and the mouse and keyboard were stuck too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the kernel has paniced (crashed), apparently when trying to get statistics from the `tg3` Broadcom NIC driver. You'll need to reset the system to let it reboot again.

You probably should update the system, or at least the kernel, to CentOS 6.[latest] and see if the crash happens again. If you have any third-party driver packages, you should update them too, or re-evaluate if they are still necessary with the latest CentOS 6.x kernel.

The latest CentOS kernels include Spectre/Meltdown fixes, and I've experienced some bad interactions (ranging from annoying "NICs locking up randomly about a week after the system is rebooted" to "100% reproducible crash at boot time") with certain proprietary pre-Spectre/Meltdown drivers when combined with post-Spectre/Meltdown kernels.

You can check any third-party modules using the `modinfo` command: if the command `modinfo <module-name> | grep retpoline` does not output the line

```
retpoline:      Y
```

then the module is from before the Spectre/Meltdown fixes and should probably be updated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there any method to record the logs when system panic or crash ?